# Inserting strings to vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, insert

I am getting a compilation error. I am trying to add strings to a vector and keep them in "sorted order".

XYZ is my class. addPortEntry

```
class XYZ
{
    public:
        portListFile(string sTmp);
        void addPortEntry(string sPortName, string sDirection);
    private:
        string sPortListFileName;
        vector <string> v_input_ports;
    ...
};

void XYZ::addP(string sP, string sDir)
{
    if(sDir == "in")
    {
        v_input_ports.insert(sP);   // Line 42
    }
    ...
}
```

Error:

```
XYZ.cpp: In member function ‘void XYZ::addP(std::string, std::string)’:
XYZ.cpp:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::insert(const char [10])’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/vector.tcc:93: note: candidates are: typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_vector.h:657: note:                 void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc> >, size_t, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >]
```

Comment: When getting compile errors on functions you (probably) haven't used, check out the documentation for the functions. You'll learn exactly how to use them, and might find something better in the same spot too. In this case, `push_back` would be listed on the side because it's also part of `vector`, and if you happened to see the name, it would grab your attention for this purpose.

Comment: I do not want to use push_back since I want the strings to be sorted. That is one of the reasons I'm using the vector.

Comment: @KingkongJnr how does one relate to the other? And why not use map then>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/) should be given an iterator to insert at a certain location. You need to use [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) instead (which is the same as `insert` with `end()` as parameter).

**edit**

You mentioned in the comments:

> I do not want to use push_back since I want the strings to be sorted.
>   That is one of the reasons I'm using the vector

I miss the logic in that statement. If you want a sorted container you should be using either [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) or [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/). Use the "multi-" versions if you want repeating values.

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned clearly the difference between the two statements. I do not want to use push_back since I want the strings to be sorted. Also, That is one of the reasons I'm using the vector (Hinting that I'm open to suggestions in case vectors couldn do it). I'll explore using std::set.

I don't want to use maps since it is not a pair of data, just one.

Eg. the individual elements are all stings like "Toyota" "Honda" etc. If it was something like "Toyota, 100" , "Honda, 300" then maps would make more sense ( I guess). 

Really appreciate your prompt response littleadv.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant `push_back` rather than `insert`?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can either append an element to a vector
(`push_back`), or you can insert it at a specified place (`insert`).  To
insert an object at a specified place, you have to specify the place;
`std::vector<>::insert` takes two arguments, the first an iterator
specifying where, and the second the value to be inserted.

You say you want to maintain the contents in sorted order.  The usual
idiom for that is to find the location using `std::lower_bound`, e.g.:

```
void
XYZ::addP( std::string const& sP, std::string const& sDir )
{
    if ( sDir == "in" ) {
        std::vector<std::string>::iterator pos
            = std::lower_bound( v_input_ports.begin(),
                                v_input_ports.end(),
                                sP );
        if ( pos != v_input_ports.end() && *pos == sDir ) {
            //  Object already present...
            *pos = sP;  //  But maybe an error is more appropriate
        } else {
            v_input_ports.insert( pos, sP );
        }
    }
}
```

Two quick comments, however:

1. You should probably be passing `std::string` by const reference,
   rather than by value.  For whatever reasons, this is the almost
   universal convention, and if you don't follow it, people will wonder
   why.
2. Any time you're concerned with order in the standard, you need to
   define the ordering relationship.  The default is `std::less<>`, which by
   default does `<`.  But functions like `std::lower_bound` can be passed
   an additional argument which defines the order in any way you want
   (subject to the constraint that it is a "strict weak ordering").  I
   mention this because the way `<` is defined on `std::string` is useless
   in most cases where you're dealing with actual text, so you may want to
   consider defining your own ordering relationship.